# Non-static class function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to create a pointer to a class non-static function to call it by several objects.

Example class:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int getNumber() { return 5; }
};
```

I have created a pointer to the class function with the same signature:

```
int (A::*funcPtr)();
```

After this, I have initialized it like this:

```
funcPtr = A::getFive;
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

> invalid use of non-static member function 'int A::getNumber()'

What is wrong in my pointer declaration? I tried to make the function `const` and change the return type, but it didn't help me.

Comment: You mean `funcPtr = &A::getNumber;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following would work:

```
funcPtr = &A::getNumber;
```